# How Can I filter out a dependency failure from app insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-keyvault

Since moving to Azure Key Vault to manage some keys and connection strings my App Insights Failures blade is producing errors when attempting to connect to Key vault.

The error is specifically: InProc | Microsoft.ManagedIdentity: EnvironmentCredential.GetToken
Azure.Identity.CredentialUnavailableException: EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.

I know what this means and it's by design.  We have chosen to use Managed Identities to handle the
Key vault connection and as such we do not have any Environment Variables set in the app to connect to the Key vault.  This is by design.

[This image shows the default connection methods for an app service to hit Key vault,  this is the default path for app services to connect to a key vault as per the MS Docs.  You can see the check for Environment Credentials fails before the successful call for the Managed Identity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nzcS.png)

So while i realize this is just tracking "how it works" i don't like to see all those failures.  My question is two-fold:

1. does this failure REALLY take no time at all? Seems that its just "how it works"
2. Can i suppress this from either being collected or reported in App Insights without having to extract the data myself and use some other reporting system?